# angular: updateRenderer throws Cannot read property 'name' of undefined for string variable

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a really strange problem with displaying a string variable. The error I'm getting is this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9912)
at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:13961)
at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:13935)
at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:14764)
at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:14704)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MonitoringCriteriaComponent.html:93)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14686)
at checkNoChangesView (core.js:13775)
at callViewAction (core.js:14126)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14104)
```

This is thrown while trying to display a string type variable like this:

```
<span>{{daysCounter}}</span>
```

The variable is declared and changed this way:

```
daysCounter = '';

public countTotalNumberOfDays() {
  this.daysCounter = '' + DateUtils.calculateNumberOfDays(this.dateFrom.datePickerTime.toDate(), this.dateTo.datePickerTime.toDate());
  console.log('daysCounter', this.daysCounter);
}
```

The error is thrown after calculation is being made, as it's properly logged in the console log, however when it is being displayed in the html template, the above error is logged. Value of this variable is not accessed anywhere else. This is within one component, other variables are visible in the template.

I don't know what else might be relevant to this problem. I'm quite stumped...

Comment: provide the source code of `calculateNumberOfDays` please

Comment: @AragornSG There are two things
 1. provide the source code to identify the issue.
 2. You can change `<span>{{daysCounter}}</span>` to this `<span>{{daysCounter | json }}</span>` to get more detail of how the daysCounter variable is getting the value from it may be you can identify the problem

Comment: Thanks guys! @v.kostenko calculateNumberOfDays was innocent here. See my answer.  Aditya, | json did not display additional information, since this was a simple string, but I did not know this method of debugging, so thanks for that! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept digging and found out that the reason for the error was a way function used to set its value was called. It was called in a (changeListener) in another component higher up, and while it was reported in console log correctly the error was thrown because the higher component, I'm guessing, did not have access to that variable. Logging in this case was very confusing.

The solution was moving the function changing the value of the var from the function used in changeListener to another spot, used only in that component.